# Database Collation in the stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, collation

I have a dump that contains the procedure for creating a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`sys`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(_Test bigint )
BEGIN
    select * from test;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

But, when I perform:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE Name LIKE '%test%'\G;
```

I get:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  Db: TEST
                Name: test
                Type: PROCEDURE
             Definer: root@%
            Modified: 2018-02-22 23:25:27
             Created: 2018-02-22 23:25:27
       Security_type: DEFINER
             Comment: 
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_general_ci
  Database Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
```

Why is `Database Collation` meaning`latin1_swedish_ci`?

Comment: The error occurs when you run the stored procedure or when restore the backup?

Answer (score 0):

For Emoji, you need `utf8mb4`, not `utf8` nor `latin1`.

I think the `Database Collation` is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your table test (and all other tables) must change the character set:

```
alter table test character set utf8mb4;
```

Also the fields that contains text:

```
alter table test change varchar_column varchar_column varchar(XX) 
                                        character set utf8mb4;
```